# how to make a function that returns a user's level?

Tags: python, function, discord.py

I recently coded a leveling system and I wasn't happy with the way it was done so I was sitting and thought of a rank command. If a user does ;rank it will then say @user, your level is [level]. Well I started to code the command and come to a point of I don't know how to make a function that can return a users level

Heres the code of the leveling system

```
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)


    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel("493185116554788894"), '{} have leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end
```

Here is what I wrote for the rank command

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def rank(ctx):
    await bot.say(f"{ctx.message.author.mention} Your rank is {lvl_end}.")
```

I am needing a funtion to return the level but I have no idea how to do that. I hope someone can help me and I imagine its alot easier than I think it is but idk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def rank(ctx):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    lvl_end = users[ctx.message.author.id]['rank']
    await bot.say(f"{ctx.message.author.mention} Your rank is {lvl_end}.")
```

Comment: That gave me an error NameError: name 'users' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the json file into it, try the updated one

Comment: Did you check it?

Comment: KeyError: 'rank'
@tyler T